# algorithm in C++

Tags: algorithm, c++11, dictionary

I am writing a multi-way trie that will load in a dictionary that will take words and phrases. So first the dictionary will be loaded into the trie.

Comment: what do you want us to do? To write a function for you based on your description?

Comment: and what do you mean by directing you? Give you a link to dfs? Explain you what is a dfs, implement you a dfs?

Comment: a sample algorithm would be very helpful, although I'm not sure this site is for that? I am new, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some (almost) C++ adapted from the following article:
http://www.toptal.com/java/the-trie-a-neglected-data-structure

That one is written in Java, so I've taken the courtesy of giving it to you in c++.

```
struct Alphabet{
    char[] x = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    int findIndex(const char* s){
       for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i){
           if(x[i] == *s){
               return i;
           }
       }

       return -1;
    }
};

struct MWTrieNode{
    std::vector::<MWTrieNode*> children;
    bool isLast = false;
}

MWTrieNode* getWord(const char* s, int len, MWTrieNode* root){

    MWTrieNode* node = root;
    Alphabet a;
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        const char* currChar = s[i];
        int index = a.findIndex(currChar);

        MWTrieNode* child = node->children[index];

        if(!child){
            // No such word
            return NULL;
        }

        // step into the MWTrieNode
        node = child;
    }

   return node;
}

// * corrected comparison between char* and char. (using *(char*))
```

You can modify the `getWord` function to take in some parameters to modify how you return your words.

But this should get you started.

For Completions, you'll need to find all of the words below a certain prefix (I'd Imagine). So you'd want' to build several "sub trees" starting with the root of your search prefix (i.e. "House" --> "Housewife", "Housing", "Household", etc.

If you pass in 'Ho', you will find a 'partial word' with no Node saying its at the end. At this point, you can start at the  'o' node.

The part you haven't mentioned is how you store words that are both a word by them selves, as well as a portion of a longer word, for example, Home, Homeowner, Homewrecker.

Those Nodes must have a

```
isLast == true
```

, but also have child nodes. it is this special case that should help you find multiple options for auto-complete. You're running the

```
getWord
```

method several times for a single search, with different prefixes and conditions. The result should be a list of words that all have the prefix you desire.

Comment: `findIndex` seems wrong - comparing a `char` with `char *`

Comment: Hey Ed! Good Catch. As I said this was "almost" c++ and I wrote it in a hurry. :). Just wanted to get him started. I guess really it should be std::string since we're talking c++.

Comment: kfsone I like the changes you made, but shouldn't you set the char* in the loop to const char* if you're going to pass it in as const? or is it just good practice to remind later coders that the char should not be modified.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure that professors Alvarado and Mirza will be highly interested in the contents of your post.